# Java Stream<Object> filter and then use the results

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I don't understand how to use the results of filtering a Stream<>. Example:

```
Stream<Edge> edgesStr = graph.edges().filter(edge -> edge.getNode1() == graph.getNode(ip2));
```

The above successfully(?) filters the Edge stream, keeping only those edges where the getNode() methods are equal.
Now after this, I want to use those results, something like:

```
//for each result
Node node = edgeStr.getNode(); //method getNode() exists for objects Edge
foo1(Node);
foo2(Node);
```

Note: graph.edges() returns a `Stream<Edges>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to perform void operations `foo1` and `foo2` on a `Node` element, for each edge, you can do it as:

```
graph.edges()
     .filter(edge -> edge.getNode() == graph.getNode(ip2))
     .map(edge -> edge.getNode()) // map edge to corresponding Node
     .forEach(node -> { foo1(node); foo2(node);}); // calls foo1 and foo2 on each node
```

Comment: I mark it as the correct answer since it is more elegant, plus it does not create a separate structure (e.g. like the List above).

Answer (score 3):

You can `collect` the results via some of the `Collector` methods, i.e. `toList` when collecting into a `List`. In order to extract the `Node` out of the `Edge` you can use `map`.

```
List<Node> edges = graph.edges()
    .filter(edge -> edge.getNode1() == graph.getNode(ip2))
    .map(edge -> edge.getNode())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```